# Can not enable Alwayson sql in DSE

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I get this error when start Alwayson sql, tried many ways but the results still same. any ideas why?
Im using 1 cluster, 1 analytics+search center, 2 ubuntu 16.04 nodes.

```
INFO  [ALWAYSON-SQL] 2019-02-14 11:36:01,348 ALWAYSON-SQL AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:304 - Shutting down AlwaysOn SQL.
INFO  [ALWAYSON-SQL] 2019-02-14 11:36:01,617 ALWAYSON-SQL AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:328 - Set status to stopped
INFO  [ALWAYSON-SQL] 2019-02-14 11:36:01,620 ALWAYSON-SQL AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:382 - Reserve port for AlwaysOn SQL
INFO  [ALWAYSON-SQL] 2019-02-14 11:36:04,621 ALWAYSON-SQL AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:375 - Release reserved port
INFO  [ALWAYSON-SQL] 2019-02-14 11:36:04,622 ALWAYSON-SQL AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:805 - Set InCluster token to DseFs client
INFO  [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] 2019-02-14 11:36:04,650  AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:740 - dsefs server heartbeat response: pong
INFO  [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] 2019-02-14 11:36:04,757  AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:704 - Create DseFs directory /var/log/spark/alwayson_sql
INFO  [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] 2019-02-14 11:36:04,758  AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:805 - Set InCluster token to DseFs client
ERROR [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] 2019-02-14 11:36:04,788  AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:722 - Failed to check dsefs directory alwayson_sql
com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient permissions to path /
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.DseFsJsonProtocol$ThrowableReader$.read(DseFsJsonProtocol.scala:258)
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.DseFsJsonProtocol$ThrowableReader$.read(DseFsJsonProtocol.scala:232)
        at spray.json.JsValue.convertTo(JsValue.scala:31)
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.rest.RestResponse$stateMachine$macro$331$1.apply(RestResponse.scala:48)
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.rest.RestResponse$stateMachine$macro$331$1.apply(RestResponse.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:465)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO  [ALWAYSON-SQL] 2019-02-14 11:36:04,788 ALWAYSON-SQL AlwaysOnSqlRunner.scala:247 - ALWAYSON-SQL caused an exception in state RUNNING : com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient permissions to path /
com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient permissions to path /
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.DseFsJsonProtocol$ThrowableReader$.read(DseFsJsonProtocol.scala:258)
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.DseFsJsonProtocol$ThrowableReader$.read(DseFsJsonProtocol.scala:232)
        at spray.json.JsValue.convertTo(JsValue.scala:31)
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.rest.RestResponse$stateMachine$macro$331$1.apply(RestResponse.scala:48)
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.rest.RestResponse$stateMachine$macro$331$1.apply(RestResponse.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:465)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem too! It was a permissions problem in dsefs! To fix, login with the root Cassandra user, and change permissions of the your alwayson log directory to the alwayson user.